# Why doesn't my SetLength work?

Tags: arrays, delphi

I tried to use SetLength to make my array shorter and it shows me incompatible types. Here's my coding:

```
    var
      A : Array[1..max] of string;
      K : Word;
...
    SetLength(A,K);
```

Is it because this array is not a dynamic array or something? If that's the problem, how do i fix it?

Comment: Yes, it is because of that. How to *fix* it ? Have a dynamic array :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use `SetLength` for **dynamic arrays** (and strings).  Your declared array is a **static array** instead.  It has a fixed length at compile-time that cannot be changed at run-time.